# ArcGIS Dashboard Date Labeling Issue Using Survey123 Data

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123, operations-dashboard

I am pulling data from Survey123 into a dashboard. I am running into an issue where data with a date in January is coming in, but the label is not (it just defaults to the year).

The date is valid. I've tried using different dates (thinking maybe January 1 was doing some UTC time calcs behind the scenes) and still the same. All other months are fine. All data is input as a date in Survey123 using a selection from a calendar.

I'm trying to figure out if this is an issue with how dashboard is reading the data or how Survey123 is storing the data - somewhere there is a disconnect.
[image: Example of Issue]

[image: How Date is Stored - Dashboard]

[image: How Date is Input/Stored - Survey123]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to ESRI support, this seems to be a bug.  They did have a workaround that seems to work - add 'MMM' as your Year format under the Category tab. This doesn't allow a Month-Year option, but at least it formats the month correctly until they get it fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also add MMM yy (or any version there of) to each field and you get January to show with the year.

[image]

Result

[image]